# rewrite rule setting in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, configuration

I install nginx 1.0.0 and i installed it /usr/local/nginx1.0.0/.
and I try to modify /usr/local/nginx1.0.0/cont/nginx.conf file.

I just copy default file. and replace **server_name** and **root** path

and I connected **example.com** -> it works (there is nginx working message.)

but I connected **www.example.com** -> it is not working.(there is 404 Not Found message.)

and url is = 
http://www.example.com/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/

and I try to server_name => example.com *.example.com (but same problum)

this is my nginx.conf code.
am i wrong config? or wrong install?

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  .example.com;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

      location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other `server {}` blocks that might have a better match for www.example.com and override this block?

Also, you probably don't want to use `fastcgi_index`. It's only useful in a few unusual circumstances. For the typical case like you have, you want to use something like

```
try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm $uri/index.php
```

in your `location / {}` block. The last item generates an internal redirect to the `location ~ \.php$ {}` block.

Comment: Just FYI, $uri/ in try_files will apply your index directive as well, so you don't need to specify all the index files. Plus, your last argument to try_files must be a guaranteed file or a named location.

Comment: thnak you friends!!!
I solved it after your advice!

Comment: I make 2 servers 
1. www.example.com
2. *.example.com
and i redirect *.example.com -> www.example.com
and i add try_files
it works greatfully!